# Receiving ARP requests from different networks (cable Internet)

Tags: arp

On the WAN interface I constantly receive ARP requests from many different networks. The source MAC address is always the same (MAC address vendor: Casa Systems Inc.).

```
22:57:57.032541 ... Request who-has 24.134.105.32 tell 24.134.105.34
22:57:57.034167 ... Request who-has 188.194.205.181 tell 188.194.205.254
22:57:57.060321 ... Request who-has 188.195.11.5 tell 188.195.11.254
22:57:57.085674 ... Request who-has 188.195.69.175 tell 188.195.69.25
22:57:57.089449 ... Request who-has 24.134.6.68 tell 24.134.6.70
22:57:57.090423 ... Request who-has 188.195.20.243 tell 188.195.20.254
22:57:57.122282 ... Request who-has 188.195.71.240 tell 188.195.71.254
22:57:57.124182 ... Request who-has 188.195.70.69 tell 188.195.70.254
```

Is this behavior common with cable Internet, it seems very inefficient to me?

Comment: If you watch long enough, you'll see ARPs for HFC (management) addresses... 10.something. (note: you *shouldn't* be able to talk to those addresses) [10.135 on my segment, and some 30.43 DoD squatting]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's common. Yes, it's stupidly inefficient. (The CMTS already knows the MAC of every device authorized to use it.)

The CMTS is just like any other router looking for the MAC to IP's in the networks it controls. There will be many overlapping networks on a CMTS. Some of this is for branding ("Earthlink Cable", "AOL Cable", etc.), but much of it is simply because there are more devices than addresses in an address block. (check the netmask of your DHCP address.)

Comment: I collected 1.1GB of ARP traffic in 24hrs (Oct 2021) That's a lot of useless traffic. [my own address was requested 3 times]